# Using Indirect within an Index function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to reference multiple worksheets depending on user input to fill in some chart data.

My only issue is referencing a named range within an index function. I am attempting to use Indirect:

`H4` being the user input named range to reference. 
`F4` being the corresponding dates named range.

`=INDEX(INDIRECT($H$4),MATCH($A3,INDIRECT($F$4),0),2)`

What is wrong with this formula?

Named ranges are correct for the cell reference. There is something wrong in how I am using indirect.

The formula comes up with a reference error.

Again, the only thing wrong is in how the indirect formula is being used. Everything else is correct. `F4` and `H4` just point to named ranges within the workbook.

Comment: what is it doing that is wrong?

Comment: And what are the contents of F4 & H4, exactly?

Comment: check that `2` argument at the end. that looks like it could be fishy in this case. if your indexed range has only one column you're going to get a #REF because 2 is out of range :)